# CloudBlob not found in the new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage what is its equivalent

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I had the following code which was using the deprecated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient and have upgraded to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and now I am unable to use the code below as it is not recognising the CloudBlob class, has this been totally removed or is there an equivalent class I can use in a similar manner

```
//blob client now
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

//the container for this is customerlogo
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

//blob reference, this will be the company name in this case. it should not exist but if it does it will get overwritten.
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(fileName);
```

Comment: Try adding `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`. Since this new library is announced, each service has its own namespace.

Comment: I have added this already but they have change the class name to CloudPageBlob and there is now also CloudBlockBlob I guess this has been added for Azure File Services support as a degree of distinction between the 2 types so in answer to my own question I believe it is CloudPageBlob

Comment: There have been many changes between this version of the library and the older one however CloudPageBlob and CloudBlockBlob are still part of blob storage. For File Service, there is a separate namespace called `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File`.

Comment: Yes but the version of the StorageClient that I had was using a class called CloudBlob which does not exist in the new namespace

Comment: @Jay did you ever solve this? If so what was your work around? I am running into the same problem - however I am trying to `DownloadText()` which is not available.

Comment: check the old documentation I believe I was using a deprecated library

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for the `DownloadText()`, it is moved to the `CloudBlockBlob` class.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Azure Storage Client Library 2.0, all blobs must be accessed via CloudPageBlob or CloudBlockBlob, since the CloudBlob base class has been removed. To get a reference to the concrete blob class when the client does not know the type, please see [CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx) and [CloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx).

For migration from a pre-2.0 release to a newer version, I would recommend reading [Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Breaking Changes & Migration Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx).