# Cannot deploy to azure cloud service due to wrong class in assembly

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

I have the problem that every deployment for a project to a could service with Visual Studio fails. The following error pops up:

```
20:14:30 - Preparing deployment for TimeJackAzure - 21.11.2015 20:06:30 with Subscription ID 'guid' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
20:14:30 - Der Typ "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob" in der Assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" konnte nicht geladen werden.
```

English error message is that

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob cannot be found in
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".

The point is, that the software is using `Microsoft.Windowsazure.Storage` in version 6.1 only...

Any Ideas how to solve this issue. Manual deployment at least do not create any error during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you switched from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, CloubBlob no longer exists.

I believe the answer is the same answer to this other question so check it out.

"Starting with Azure Storage Client Library 2.0, all blobs must be accessed via CloudPageBlob or CloudBlockBlob, since the CloudBlob base class has been removed."

[CloudBlob not found in the new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage what is its equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158252/cloudblob-not-found-in-the-new-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-what-is-its-equiva)

Comment: mhhh.. I'm aware of this change, None of my libraries and source code is using the old stuff... Checked again just now.. nope

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue.. 
I use visual studio 2015 - and had azure sdk 2.9 installed
here is what i did...
(after lot of trouble shooting... and wasting a day on it...)
(get process explorer and look for what storage assembly was loaded)

fix was basically rest my local profile...
here is what worked for me... (alternatively reset profile using visualstudio reset...this might be safer...)

C:\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

rename 14.0 folder to something else.. (14.0_back)

after this.. it picks the right assembly